# Unable to see sonarqube analysis in sonarqube server after build success

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

When I tried to analyze a java program using maven for SonarQube 5.6 analysis I am unable to see analysis result on dashboard. I added all the plugins and build steps in my `pom.xml` and executed `mvn clean deploy`.

Nevertheless my build shows success but the analysis is not posting on SonarQube server and in background task it shows failed (in SonarQube server web UI)

My `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.analysis</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello.sonar</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>hello.sonar</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jacoco.version>0.7.9</jacoco.version>
    <surefire.version>2.19.1</surefire.version>
    <sonar.host.url>http://sonarurl:9000</sonar.host.url>
</properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
<build>
                <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-instrument</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>instrument</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-report</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.0.603</version>
                        <executions>
                                <execution>
                                <id>sonar</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                        <goal>sonar</goal>
                                </goals>
                        </execution>
                        </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
</project>​
```

And the output is:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building sonar.analysis 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) @ sonar.analysis ---
[INFO] User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
[INFO] Load global repositories
[INFO] Load global repositories (done) | time=128ms
[INFO] Server id: xxxxxxxxx
[INFO] User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
[INFO] Load plugins index
[INFO] Load plugins index (done) | time=2ms
[INFO] SonarQube version: 5.6.6
[INFO] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[INFO] Process project properties
[INFO] Load project repositories
[INFO] Load project repositories (done) | time=90ms
[INFO] Load quality profiles
[INFO] Load quality profiles (done) | time=25ms
[INFO] Load active rules
[INFO] Load active rules (done) | time=248ms
[WARNING] SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
[INFO] Publish mode
[INFO] -------------  Scan sonar.analysis
[INFO] Load server rules
[INFO] Load server rules (done) | time=62ms
[INFO] Base dir: /root/mvn/sonar.analysis
[INFO] Working dir: /root/mvn/sonar.analysis/target/sonar
[INFO] Source paths: pom.xml, src/main/java
[INFO] Test paths: src/test/java
[INFO] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] Index files
[INFO] 2 files indexed
[INFO] Quality profile for java: Sonar way
[INFO] Sensor Lines Sensor
[INFO] Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=11ms
[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor
[INFO] Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 5
[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization
[WARNING] Bytecode of dependencies was not provided for analysis of source files, you might end up with less precise results. Bytecode can be provided using sonar.java.libraries property
[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization
[INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization (done) | time=9ms
[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan
[INFO] 1 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan (done) | time=288ms
[INFO] 1/1 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Java Test Files AST scan
[INFO] 1 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] 1/1 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Java Test Files AST scan (done) | time=68ms
[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor (done) | time=747ms
[INFO] Sensor SCM Sensor
[INFO] No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.
[INFO] Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor
[INFO] parsing /root/mvn/sonar.analysis/target/surefire-reports
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor
[INFO] JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found : /root/mvn/sonar.analysis/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoItSensor
[INFO] JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: /root/mvn/sonar.analysis/target/jacoco-it.exec
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoItSensor (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor XmlFileSensor
[INFO] Sensor XmlFileSensor (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=6ms
[INFO] Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
[INFO] Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer
[INFO] JavaCpdBlockIndexer is used for java
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=19ms
[INFO] Calculating CPD for 0 files
[INFO] CPD calculation finished
[INFO] Analysis report generated in 64ms, dir size=14 KB
[INFO] Analysis reports compressed in 27ms, zip size=8 KB
[INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 34ms
[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://sonarurl:9000/dashboard/index/com.bbt:sonar.analysis
[INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
[INFO] More about the report processing at http://sonarurl:9000/api/ce/task?id=AVzQPhItA
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`Log files`

```html
2017.07.03 00:00:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42726 created by (ConnectionID:xxx ClientConnectionId: 6xxx-5xxxxe-4bxxx4-8xxd-4363xxx5)
2017.07.03 00:00:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42726 Executing (not server cursor) SELECT 1
2017.07.03 00:00:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43662 created by (SQLServerStatement:42726)
2017.07.03 00:00:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42727 created by (ConnectionID:xxx ClientConnectionId: 6xxx-xxxe-4bxxx-8xx-4xxxxxxx9xxx5)
2017.07.03 00:00:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42727: calling sp_prepexec: PreparedHandle:0, SQL:select top (@P0) id, data
    from notifications
    order by id asc        
2017.07.03 00:00:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43xx3 created by (SQLServerPreparedStatement:42727)
2017.07.03 00:00:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSetMetaData]  SQLServerResultSetMetaData:24383 created by (SQLServerResultSet:43663)
2017.07.03 00:01:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:4xx28 created by (ConnectionID:1557 ClientConnectionId: 6xxxx-xxxe-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx)
2017.07.03 00:01:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42xx8 Executing (not server cursor) SELECT 1
2017.07.03 00:01:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43xx4 created by (SQLServerStatement:42728)
2017.07.03 00:01:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42xxx9 created by (ConnectionID:1557 ClientConnectionId: 66xxxx4e-4xxxx-8xxx-4363xxxx)
2017.07.03 00:01:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42729: calling sp_prepexec: PreparedHandle:0, SQL:select top (@P0) id, data
    from notifications
    order by id asc        
2017.07.03 00:01:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43665 created by (SQLServerPreparedStatement:42729)
2017.07.03 00:01:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSetMetaData]  SQLServerResultSetMetaData:24384 created by (SQLServerResultSet:43665)
2017.07.03 00:02:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42730 created by (ConnectionID:1557 ClientConnectionId: 6xxxx-5xxxx-4bxxxx-8xxx-43xxxxxx)
2017.07.03 00:02:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42730 Executing (not server cursor) SELECT 1
2017.07.03 00:02:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43666 created by (SQLServerStatement:42730)
2017.07.03 00:02:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42731 created by (ConnectionID:1557 ClientConnectionId: 6xxxx-5xxxx-4bxxxx-8xxx-43xxxxxx)
2017.07.03 00:02:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42731: calling sp_prepexec: PreparedHandle:0, SQL:select top (@P0) id, data
    from notifications
    order by id asc        
2017.07.03 00:02:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43667 created by (SQLServerPreparedStatement:42731)
2017.07.03 00:02:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSetMetaData]  SQLServerResultSetMetaData:24385 created by (SQLServerResultSet:43667)
2017.07.03 00:03:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42732 created by (ConnectionID:1557 ClientConnectionId: 6xxxx-5xxxx-4bxxxx-8xxx-43xxxxxx)
2017.07.03 00:03:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42732 Executing (not server cursor) SELECT 1
2017.07.03 00:03:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43668 created by (SQLServerStatement:42732)
2017.07.03 00:03:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42733 created by (ConnectionID:1557 ClientConnectionId: 6xxxx-5xxxx-4bxxxx-8xxx-43xxxxxx)
2017.07.03 00:03:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42733: calling sp_prepexec: PreparedHandle:0, SQL:select top (@P0) id, data
    from notifications
    order by id asc        
2017.07.03 00:03:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43669 created by (SQLServerPreparedStatement:42733)
2017.07.03 00:03:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSetMetaData]  SQLServerResultSetMetaData:24386 created by (SQLServerResultSet:43669)
2017.07.03 00:03:38 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerDriver] Property:serverName Value:servername
2017.07.03 00:03:38 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerDriver] Property:portNumber Value:xxx
2017.07.03 00:03:38 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerDriver] Property:databaseName Value:Databasename
2017.07.03 00:03:38 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection] ConnectionID:1558 created by (SQLServerDriver:1)
2017.07.03 00:03:38 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection] ConnectionID:1558 This attempt server name: Database servername port: xxx InstanceName: null useParallel: false
2017.07.03 00:03:38 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection] ConnectionID:1558 This attempt endtime: 1499054633746
2017.07.03 00:03:38 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection] ConnectionID:1558 This attempt No: 0
2017.07.03 00:03:38 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection] ConnectionID:1558 Connecting with server: servername port: 55xx Timeout slice: 15000 Timeout Full: 15
2017.07.03 00:03:38 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection] ConnectionID:1558 ClientConnectionId: 9xxx-4xxx-9xx-5c9xxxxx) Server returned major version:12
2017.07.03 00:04:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42734 created by (ConnectionID:1558 ClientConnectionId: 9xxxxxx-8xxxxxx-4xxxxxxx-9xxxx-5xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
2017.07.03 00:04:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42734 Executing (not server cursor) SELECT 1
2017.07.03 00:04:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43670 created by (SQLServerStatement:42734)
2017.07.03 00:04:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42735 created by (ConnectionID:1558 ClientConnectionId: 9xxxxxx-8xxxxxx-4xxxxxxx-9xxxx-5xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
2017.07.03 00:04:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42735: calling sp_prepexec: PreparedHandle:0, SQL:select top (@P0) id, data
    from notifications
    order by id asc        
2017.07.03 00:04:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43671 created by (SQLServerPreparedStatement:42735)
2017.07.03 00:04:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSetMetaData]  SQLServerResultSetMetaData:24387 created by (SQLServerResultSet:43671)
2017.07.03 00:04:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData]  SQLServerDatabaseMetaData:1556 created by (ConnectionID:1558 ClientConnectionId: 9xxx-4xxx-9xx-5c9xxxxx)
2017.07.03 00:05:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42736 created by (ConnectionID:1558 ClientConnectionId: 9xxx-4xxx-9xx-5c9xxxxx)
2017.07.03 00:05:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42736 Executing (not server cursor) SELECT 1
2017.07.03 00:05:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43672 created by (SQLServerStatement:42736)
2017.07.03 00:05:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42737 created by (ConnectionID:1558 ClientConnectionId: 9xxx-4xxx-9xx-5c9xxxxx)
2017.07.03 00:05:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42737: calling sp_prepexec: PreparedHandle:0, SQL:select top (@P0) id, data
    from notifications
    order by id asc        
2017.07.03 00:05:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43673 created by (SQLServerPreparedStatement:42737)
2017.07.03 00:05:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSetMetaData]  SQLServerResultSetMetaData:24388 created by (SQLServerResultSet:43673)
2017.07.03 00:06:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42738 created by (ConnectionID:1558 ClientConnectionId: 9xxx-4xxx-9xx-5c9xxxxx)
2017.07.03 00:06:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42738 Executing (not server cursor) SELECT 1
2017.07.03 00:06:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43674 created by (SQLServerStatement:42738)
2017.07.03 00:06:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42739 created by (ConnectionID:1558 ClientConnectionId: 9xxx-4xxx-9xx-5c9xxxxx)
2017.07.03 00:06:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42739: calling sp_prepexec: PreparedHandle:0, SQL:select top (@P0) id, data
    from notifications
    order by id asc        
2017.07.03 00:06:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43675 created by (SQLServerPreparedStatement:42739)
2017.07.03 00:06:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSetMetaData]  SQLServerResultSetMetaData:24389 created by (SQLServerResultSet:43675)
2017.07.03 00:07:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42740 created by (ConnectionID:1558 ClientConnectionId: 9xxx-4xxx-9xx-5c9xxxxx)
2017.07.03 00:07:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42740 Executing (not server cursor) SELECT 1
2017.07.03 00:07:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43676 created by (SQLServerStatement:42740)
2017.07.03 00:07:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42741 created by (ConnectionID:1558 ClientConnectionId: 9xxx-4xxx-9xx-5c9xxxxx)
2017.07.03 00:07:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42741: calling sp_prepexec: PreparedHandle:0, SQL:select top (@P0) id, data
    from notifications
    order by id asc        
2017.07.03 00:07:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43677 created by (SQLServerPreparedStatement:42741)
2017.07.03 00:07:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSetMetaData]  SQLServerResultSetMetaData:24390 created by (SQLServerResultSet:43677)
2017.07.03 00:08:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42742 created by (ConnectionID:1558 ClientConnectionId: 9xxx-4xxx-9xx-5c9xxxxx)
2017.07.03 00:08:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerStatement:42742 Executing (not server cursor) SELECT 1
2017.07.03 00:08:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerResultSet] SQLServerResultSet:43678 created by (SQLServerStatement:42742)
2017.07.03 00:08:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42743 created by (ConnectionID:1558 ClientConnectionId: 9xxx-4xxx-9xx-5c9xxxxx)
2017.07.03 00:08:15 DEBUG web[c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerStatement] SQLServerPreparedStatement:42743: calling sp_prepexec: PreparedHandle:0, SQL:select top (@P0) id, data
    from notifications
    order by id asc
```

Comment: what does your server logs tell you... please check sonar.log and web.log

Comment: Your analysis log indicates that the analysis report was posted to the server.  On the SonarQube side you should have a status for the processing of that report. Perhaps it was still queued or in process when you looked?

Comment: @G.Ann when I check my Background task it still shows failed even after very long time. it worked well before but suddenly it stopped working as failing all analysis

Comment: So you need to check your... ce.log, I believe, to see why report processing failed.

Comment: @G.Ann I added my logs. thanks again

Comment: @SimonSchrottner When I see log files I didn't seen any issues and I added my log files for reference

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam can you please help me out. In logs I couldn't see anything. but when I tried to take out the database and ran sonarqube using embedded database it went well