# Sonarqube 5.6 analys is failing in background with out logs

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

Hi I am facing this issue from very long time. I didn't got any help so I tried to repost it again and this is my old question [Unable to see sonarqube analysis in sonarqube server after build success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702658/unable-to-see-sonarqube-analysis-in-sonarqube-server-after-build-success). For more information
   `I am using MSSQL shared database for my sonarqube.`
 I am not having any error logs to figure out my issue. But when I take out my database and ran with embedded database it was running fine. But when I run by configuring my MSSQL database I am having Intermittent analysis failures. My environment is Sonarqube 5.6 in Linux, database MSSQL 14.

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Do you use SonarQube 5.6.6? Do you use Integrated Login? Do you perform the analysis using an user known in MSSQL and has dbo rights? Did you set the SonarQube log level to debug? Did you update all plugins?

Comment: What worked is, my database got corrupted due to multiple sonarqube server connections. so I got a new one whilch helped to solve my issue. thanks @JeroenHeier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Used another Database which helped to resolve my issue. when I get this issue I tried analysis using embedded database and hen I came to know that Due to database conflict its unable to analyze code and failing in background. so I changed my database as I don't have important data helped me to resolve this issue